# Sumar las horas totales trabajadas durante 1 mes

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como puedo sumar las horas en un lapso de 1 mes, a partir de una fechaInicial y 
una fechaFinal de tal forma que el resultado sea de la siguiente forma:

```
Code    fechaActual   idClave   nombre       HorasTotalesMes    

2300      2017-12        14290        NombreUsuario             37
```

La consulta actual que ejecuto es la siguiente:

```
select c.CodeCompany,
    CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS fechaActual,
    a.idClave,
    c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
    d.Descripcion as Depto, 
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada,
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,
   DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24 AS sumaHoras

        from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
             JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto

         where 

            fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-11-01 00:00:00',103) and 
            CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-11-30 23:59:59',103)
```

Sin embargo esta consulta los muestra de la siguiente forma:

```
Code fechaActual idClave nombre                         HorasTotalesMes 
2300  201712  14290  User3  14:03:36    21:35:11             7
2300  201712  14290  User3  13:43:33    21:36:34             8
2300  201712  14290  User3  13:56:38    21:02:15             8
2300  201712  14290  User3  13:54:01    21:37:26             8
2300  201712  14290  User3  06:00:00    00:00:00             6
```

Comment: Solo te falta agrupar esa salida y ya tienes el resultado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilizando el group by:

```
select 
    c.CodeCompany,
    CONVERT(char(6), GETDATE(), 112) AS fechaActual,
    a.idClave,
    c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre,
    d.Descripcion as Depto, 
    --CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaEntrada,108) AS fechaEntrada,
    --CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),fechaSalida,108) AS fechaSalida,
    sum(DATEDIFF(HOUR, fechaEntrada, fechaSalida) %24) AS sumaHoras
from tblasistencia a JOIN tblpersonal c ON a.idClave=c.idClave
     JOIN tblDepto d ON c.fkDepto=d.idDepto
where fechaEntrada BETWEEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '2017-11-01 00:00:00',103) and 
      CONVERT(DATETIME,'2017-11-30 23:59:59',103)
group by c.CodeCompany
      , CONVERT(char(6)
      , GETDATE(), 112)
      , a.idClave
      , c.nombre + ' ' + c.apellidos as Nombre
      , d.Descripcion
```

Algo así, agregas SUM en el campo que quieres sumarizar y agrupas por todos los demás campos, en el caso de los campos de fecha que dan distintos, si es necesario quitarlos porque si no el group no funcionara, debido a que son distintos todos.

El group funciona para agrupar campos iguales...